# Android Recycler View notifyItemRemoved animation cut off

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm currently working on a Grade Manager for school written in Java for Android 6. I just started with Android so I'm no expert.

**The Problem:**
If I call the method `notifyItemRemoved()` on my RecycleView Adapter and the last CardView moves from the left bottom place to the upper right place, the View is resized and the animation is cut of.

Now I don't know why that view is resized because RecycleView's `layout_height` attribute is `match_parent`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".SemesterActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_semester">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/subject_list_view"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I took a `GridLayoutManager` as LayoutManager for the RecycleView.

```
subjectListView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(ActivityContext, 2));
```

How i update the RecycleView:

```
SubjectAdapterObj.notifyItemRemoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

The animation is the default animation.

Could the `GridLayoutManager` be the problem?

**Video Example:**

[image: Animation cut off]

Comment: What is the recyclerview version you are using?

Comment: recycleview-v7-23.4.0 is it that what you mean?

Comment: Try overriding `onMeasure` of `RecyclerView` and set max-height.

Comment: Also check if anywhere in the view heirarchy a parent has height="wrap_content"

Comment: @Abbas if i try to override RecyclerView I always get:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #65: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class

Comment: That could be for multiple reasons, add your updated `xml` for `RecyclerView` and also the *extended* `RecyclerView` in Java code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I finally found out what the problem was.
It actually was the `NestedScrollView` which resizes it's children.
So what you need to do is to simply add `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `NestedScrollView`.

Thats it. I hope it helps someone although it's not a really difficult bug. I just searched at the wrong places.